# How do I get a Mac-like Gnome panel/menu bar (which changes accordingly to the active window).

Tags: 12.04, gnome, panel, menu

So in Firefox, I would have the top panel change to

File Edit View ... etc

and in Photoshop it would be File Edit Image Select ... etc.

On top of that, this function would make those menu bars in the windows themselves obsolete, so I need to get rid of those.

Comment: Can you clarify your question with screenshot

Comment: @Tachyons I'm pretty sure OP was asking pretty much what I'm asking in this [related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/850535/how-to-get-the-menus-to-display-in-the-panel-rather-than-in-individual-windows-i) only for a different desktop environment. There are screenshots in the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you provide more information? Unity already comes with a global menu.
But if you use GNOME2 or GNOME3 you can use the globalmenu package.
You can find more information here:

http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/

And install instructions over here:

http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/wiki/Installation

This adds the same global menu as in Unity.

Answer (score -2):

Check this article http://www.cornext.com/2012/08/activate-global-menu-using-gnome.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.