# Unity's "File Edit View" menus in Gnome Fallback in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: unity, gnome, gnome-classic

I was recently playing around with Ubuntu 11.04 (Ah, the last version of Ubuntu to use Gnome 2 in the background) and I noticed this:

[image: File Edit View Menu's in GNOME]

As you can see its the "Unity" "File Edit View..." menu in GNOME 2. It's available as an indicator addon in 11.04.

Now what I'm asking is how do I get this integrated menu to the top bar in GNOME Fallback/Classic in Ubuntu 12.04? As it will be a great addition on my custom distro. Its also good for saving space on smaller screens like on my netbook. (Wink wink, nudge nudge. Hmm, maybe thats why he wants the answer)

It would also be nicer if it hid when the mouse isn't over it, but that's just a perk, but it would be nice ;)

I can confirm that the answer by `tabakisp` works! Thank you tabakisp!

Comment: DO NOT edit your topic to add "[Accepting Answers]" again.  Until this question has an answer marked as "Accepted" it is assumed you are accepting answers.  Adding "Accepting Answers" to your title only bumps this thread, and you should not do that.  (The fact that both me and a moderator have had to reverse this means that you should listen to this comment.  Check the [revision history](http://askubuntu.com/posts/418198/revisions) to see what I mean by me and a moderator both reversing this change.)

Comment: That's not why he removed it.  Putting additional irrelevant information in the topic JUST to bump the question (which is really what you were doing) is why myself and fossfreedom and others removed that from your title.

Comment: Patience is better. And just as an FYI, if you continued to bump your posts, you could've gotten your post edit-locked so that NOBODY but mods could edit.  Constantly reverting one's edits just because you *want* something in the title, when it's not supposed to be in the title, usually ends up in an "edit war" and posts get locked.  Don't bump your posts, basically.

Comment: Yep, all's good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If you use GNOME2 or GNOME3 you can use the globalmenu package.

You can find more information [here](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/)

And install instructions over [here](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/wiki/Installation)

This adds the same global menu as in Unity.*

**Answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141636/how-do-i-get-a-mac-like-gnome-panel-menu-bar-which-changes-accordingly-to-the-a).**

Edit:

In order for this guide to work for 12.04 Precise, you also need `sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk libqtgui4 indicator-applet-appmenu indicator-appmenu` and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right-Click, `Add to Panel...`, and add `Indicator Applet Appmenu`

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted :). But does it auto hide?

Comment: Not sure, but you can use the info that @fossfreedom posted

Comment: @davidbuddy9 Did you even try it?

Comment: Ok, I can confirm this works! PS, It works better than I thought, I just wanted the auto hide because I didn't want it to show "File, Edit, View" when on the black desktop as in 11.04, but in 12.04 it hide's it's self when on the blank desktop