# No matter what desktop environment, how do I get a permanent global application menu?

Tags: appmenu

Permanent global application menu somehow? Doesn’t have to be Unity, but should work in 12.04 or newer.

Permanent means: one which doesn’t disappear after two seconds.
Global application menu means: the application menu is not in it’s window but in a (top-)panel. – Eats less space if a permanent panel exists and is not full yet (so the menu fits in there).

Comment: What do you mean by permanent? ...and what's wrong with it in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Some desktop environments (like KDE) don't really have the concept of a global menu. Therefore, I don't think there is a true solution to this.

Comment: What's a global menu? You mean the OSX-style thing that unity has implemented?

Comment: By "disappear", do you mean where the menu is replaced with the application title? As in, you want the application title *and* the menu bar displayed at all times?

Comment: Its possible in gnome though. Check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/418198/unitys-file-edit-view-menus-in-gnome-fallback-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: you could mimic it in Xfce, by playing with the top-panel persistance, but it'll never be a true global menu.

Comment: Try searching for "Classicmenu indicator" available in the software centre.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The OP is asking for this feature irrespective of which desktop environment is in use. The linked dupe is only about gnome. There _are_ other DEs!