# How to get the menu to display in the panel rather than in individual windows in Xfce?

Tags: 16.04, xfce, menu, panel

Lately, I've been using Xfce more and Unity less. One of the things I miss from Unity is the position of the "menus". (In this case, they say "Media, Edit", etc., what are these called, by the way? Menus?)

In Unity, they are always positioned in the panel at the very top of the screen.

[image]

In Xfce, on the other hand, they follow each individual application and window, and are not displayed in the panel by default.

[image]

I prefer the way Unity does it. Can I make these menus display in the panel in Xfce too? And maybe even make them disappear from the individual windows?

I believe I'm asking the same thing like [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141636/how-do-i-get-a-mac-like-gnome-panel-menu-bar-which-changes-accordingly-to-the-a?rq=1), only for Xfce rather than GNOME.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command to install some packages:

```
sudo apt install xfce4-topmenu-plugin libtopmenu-client-gtk2-0 libtopmenu-server-gtk2-0 libtopmenu-client-gtk3-0 libtopmenu-server-gtk3-0 topmenu-gtk2 topmenu-gtk3
```

Create a file by using this command:

```
pkexec mousepad /etc/profile.d/topmenu-gtk.sh
```

In the text editor that appears, paste the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GTK_MODULES=$GTK_MODULES:topmenu-gtk-module
```

Save the document. Log out and in from the system. Right click on the Xfce panel and select **Panel**, then **Add new items**. From the list, select "**TopMenu**". Done!

Attribution: Everything is from this [tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/05/how-to-get-global-menu-in-xubuntu-1604.html), which features instructions for MATE and Lubuntu too.

Answer (score 1):

Since topmenu now doesn't support apps based on Qt and libreoffice,chrome...

Here's another alternative  **Vala Panel AppMenu**

Vala Panel AppMenu is a global menu panel applet for Xfce, MATE and Vala panels, which uses unity-gtk-module as its backend, and it works with all the applications supported by Unity's AppMenu.

Add repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/mate
```

Install the plugin

```
sudo apt install xfce4-vala-appmenu-plugin unity-gtk3-module unity-gtk2-module appmenu-qt appmenu-qt5
```

Disable the menu from being displayed in application windows

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/ShellShowsMenubar -n -t bool -s true
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/ShellShowsAppmenu -n -t bool -s true
```

Restart the session (logout, then log back in).

Add the Vala AppMenu applet to the panel

Must read for instructions of both XFCE and MATE - [Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/02/alternative-global-menu-for-mate-and.html)